# Subset data for binary logistic regression for accuracy in word/nonword categorisation

Tags: r, binary, regression, subset

I need to subset my data into 1/0 for correct responses to perform a binary logistic regression (to measure accuracy in a word/nonword categorisation task). The original data is 1 for word and 2 for non-word.
How I can change this to (yes = 1 and no = 2) and then change this to 1 and 0?
here is the information from the data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3CFA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it done in two steps? It would be easier to answer if we had an example of your data. Something like below might help:

```
data$yes_no <- ifelse(data$word == 1, "yes", "no")
data$response <- ifelse(data$word == 1, 1, 0)
```